# Remote Debugging Raspberry Pi 0W

Tags: python, pi-zero

Using Visual Studio to debug python applications on a Raspberry Pi 2 or newer is a real convenience, but Visual Studio Code does not support debugging on Raspberry Pi 0 or 0 W because of the older CPU. Is there a way/hack to get VS Code working with a Raspberry Pi 0 W or are there better alternatives out there?

Comment: Don't you think that Pi Zero would be supported if there was a way? And what do you mean by "alternatives"? Alternatives to MS VS, to RPi, to Python, to remote debugging, etc.

Comment: Why not develop on a 'better' Pi and move the code over?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself yet, but for anyone who stumbles on this from Google:
https://bitbucket.org/jIRI/rasp-pi-zerow-vscode/src/master/

Comment: Appears to be Windows-only, unless I missed something.

Comment: You'll have to update the scripts for other OSes, but the basic system should work about the same